# Related products are not showing on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, related-products

I'running my M1 shop for some years now. 
But I never used related products before.

I use a single column template and like to show related products at bottom of product page.

So at a config. product I add some related products, but they don't show anywhere.
So I must be missing some setting.

Could anyone explain me what steps / settings to do in order to get the related products visible in frontend?

John

Answer (score 0):

> ***Solution:***
>
> Login to ***Admin***
>
> Go to ***System -> Index Management***
>
> ***Select All checkboxes***
>
> Select ***'Reindex Data'*** from Actions selection list
>
> ***Click Submit button***

then clear cache  ***System -> Cache Management -> Flush Cache Storage*** after that Check again

Comment: Thank you, I all ready tried that without succes.